# Record are not imported fully from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a csv file which I convert to Excel, it contains about 890000 records,
Now When I am importing it to Access using the code it only import records upto 65535. Even If I have simple excel file contains records more than 66000, It will only import 65535 records.

```
   Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
   xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

   Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
            strFile = Dir(varItem)
            strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
                "File: " & strFile
        Next
    End If
a = strFolder & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        transfertype:=acImport, _
        TableName:="Table_Name", _
        FileName:=a, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Data" & "!A1:AL" & ls_last_row
```

I am using Access 2010 and Excel 2010.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of *ls_last_row* and where does it come from?

Comment: @HansUp Its a counter which exclude the empty row if exist and returns the number of rows.

Comment: What is the value of *ls_last_row*?  Insert `MsgBox ls_last_row` on the line before `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.  Run the code.  What number is displayed in the message box?

Comment: @HansUp the number of total rows in the excelsheet.

Comment: @HansUp I have change somecode according to given answer but its given error some time  3275 Unexpected error occur or some time system resources exceed or not enough systems resources.

Comment: why i get -2 ? on this question ? :( read my profile i am not a full time programmer just doing this to make my daily task easier and i find this stackexchange so much helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the spreadsheet type in the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` call:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        Spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        transfertype:=acImport, _
        TableName:="Table_Name", _
        FileName:=a, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Data" & "!A1:AL" & ls_last_row
```

it might be `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel14` for 2010... I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Access has a record count limitation of ~65,000 rows when it comes to import/export.  This limitation might be causing your issue.  For example, if you try to export a table using the data export options on the ribbon, and your table contains more than ~65,000 rows, access will give you a warning that all the rows might not be exported.